# Как оптимизировать изображения в отдельную папку в webpack?

Tags: изображения, webpack

Использую `imagemin-webpack-plugin` и не удается сохранить оптимизированные изображения в отдельную папку `./dist/images`. Все сохраняет в корень, указанный в `output`.

Вот мой конфиг:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'); //to access built-in plugins
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const DEV_MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/[name].css");

const config = {
  entry: './dev/entry.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'scripts/bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: DEV_MODE ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: extractSass.extract({
        use: [{
          loader: "css-loader", options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader", options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }]
      })
    },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractSass,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './dev/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$' : 'jquery'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: './dev/images/'
    }]),
    new ImageminPlugin({ test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

У самого плагина нашел только опцию "`destination`" но она не срабатывает.

Answer (score 3):

Вот кусок кода, который решит проблему:

```
...
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        context: ''
    }
}
...
```

Принцип следующий: file-loader копирует файлы в нужную папку, а `imagemin-webpack-plugin` оптимизирует их независимо от того, в какое местоположение они складываются. Поэтому у `imagemin-webpack-plugin` нет параметра для указания пути - он ему не нужен.

На всякий случай оставлю здесь вариант с `image-webpack-loader`:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg)$/,
    use: [
        'file-loader?name=../images/[name].[ext]',
        {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {}
        },

    ],
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Автору наверное уже поздно, но остальным объясню:

`imagemin` ничего никуда не перекладывает. Он оптимизирует изображения независимо от того, как они к нему попали. Что касается проблемы, то ее можно легко обойти c помощью `file-loader`, который будет складывать уже оптимизированные изображения в нужную папку.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример конфига?

Comment: @Hett https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836129/195991